Unable to filter records in collection based on where clause values
I have a collection with 2 columns
Create or replace type typ_tbl_column is table of typ_OBJ_column;

Create or replace type type_OBJ_column  is object
(Col1 varchar2(4000),
Col2 varchar2(4000);

Creat or replace type type_tbl_emo is table of number;

Declare
Lv_tbl_RU_record_list  typ_tbl_column;
Lv_tbl_emo type_tbl_emo;

Begin
Select typ_obj_column(emo_no, emo_name) bulk collect into lv_tbl_RU_record_list from employee_details;

Now, when I do
Select col1 bulk collect into lv_tbl_emo from table(lv_tbl_RU_record_list) where col2 in ('Sam','prince');

End;
/

Its giving zero count. But when I remove where clause it returns 2 rows.. Please let me know what is wrong with where clause

If you:

fix the typos in your code;
make sure that you create the object type before the table type; and
have some sample data that matches the values you are filtering for.

Then your code works:
CREATE TABLE employee_details(emo_no, emo_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Diana' FROM DUAL
/

Create type typ_OBJ_column is object (
  Col1 varchar2(4000),
  Col2 varchar2(4000)
)
/

Create type typ_tbl_emo is table of number
/

Create type typ_tbl_column is table of typ_OBJ_column
/

Declare
  Lv_tbl_RU_record_list typ_tbl_column;
  Lv_tbl_emo            typ_tbl_emo;
Begin
  Select typ_obj_column(emo_no, emo_name)
  bulk collect into lv_tbl_RU_record_list
  from   employee_details;
  
  Select col1
  bulk   collect into lv_tbl_emo
  from   table(lv_tbl_RU_record_list)
  where  col2 in ('Alice','Carol');
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. lv_tbl_emo.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_tbl_emo(i));
  END LOOP;
 END;
 /

Outputs:
1
3

fiddle

Thanks for the output..if i add 'Alice',carol' into a variable and substitute in clause, then its not working..please help

@NarasimhanM It works for me fiddle

Please could you post the variable substituting both the names 'in condition' for learning purpose like lv_name_details ='Alice,Carol' Select col1
bulk   collect into lv_tbl_emo
from   table(lv_tbl_RU_record_list)
where  col2 in (lv_name_details);

@NarasimhanM You cannot put two values into a single value - a single value is exactly that, one value. If you want multiple values then use multiple values or use a collection. fiddle
